# Multiple Array[] along with mapping handling

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ether, remix

This code is running but when the same user makes a bid then the bid is being replaced from the first bid and event is printing twice the same record.

I want that one address make a bid and for his 2nd bid code record both of his bids along with his address.

Please suggest the rectification.

Thanks

My Code for Bidding Contract:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract bidding {
  address[] private bidderAccts;

  struct bidStruct {
    uint  bid;
  }
  mapping (address => bidStruct) biddersMap;

  event totalAccounts(address, uint );

  function setBidders(address _address , uint _bid)  public {
    bidStruct a = biddersMap[_address];
    a.bid = _bid;
    bidderAccts.push(_address) - 1 ;
  }

  function getBidders(address _address) view public returns(uint) {
    return biddersMap[_address].bid;
  }

  function countBidders() view public returns (uint) {
    return bidderAccts.length;
  }

  function allBidders() public  {
    for (uint i = 0; i < bidderAccts.length; i++) {
      emit totalAccounts(bidderAccts[i],biddersMap[bidderAccts[i]].bid);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `bidderAccts.push(_address) - 1`???

Comment: BTW, you might want to add an input argument in function `allBidders` to indicate the maximum number of iterations. Otherwise, at some point you might reach a case where this function can no longer be executed because it exceeds block size.

Comment: Also, you need to change `bidStruct a` to `bidStruct storage a`. I'm not sure why the compiler hasn't warned you about this.

Comment: @goodvibration `.push() -1` returns a row. It's not assigned to anything, so useless in this case. I imagine picked up from other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Things get awkward because the storage structure doesn't align with the requirements. I refactored with a storage structure that reflects the requirements as described.

This might be more like what you want. No warranty.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract bidding {

    address[] public bidderAccts;

    // For each address, there are 0-n bids
    mapping (address => uint[]) public bids;

    event LogNewBidder(address newBidder);
    event LogNewBid(address bidder, uint bid);

    function isBidder(address bidder) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
        // has bid before
        return bids[bidder].length > 0;
    }

    function upsertBidder(address bidder) public {
        if(!isBidder(bidder)) {
            bidderAccts.push(bidder);
            emit LogNewBidder(bidder);
        }
    }

    function setBid(uint bid)  public {
            // there is no known rule about minimum bid, but let's say 0 is too low.
            require(bid > 0);
            upsertBidder(msg.sender);
            bids[msg.sender].push(bid);
            emit LogNewBid(msg.sender, bid);
    }

     function getUniqueBidderCount() view public returns (uint) {
        return bidderAccts.length;
    }       

}
```

I made a judgment decision that it is more decentralized to imagine that the bidders themselves declare their bid, so `setBid` attacks it from the perspective that `msg.sender` will be the bidder. If you have a more centralized idea in mind and a server will be processing the bids, then pass in `address bidder` as you were and use that in place of `msg.sender`.

Hope it helps.